# Resizing image to properly fit screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a Reddit slideshow app, but I am having trouble getting images to properly fit on the screen, even using bootstrap.  The relevant lines of code are:

```
<div id="curtain" class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">

 $('#curtain').html("<img src='"+imgArr[i]+"'>").css("height","auto").css("width", "auto").css("max-height","100vh").css("max-width","100vw").css("object-fit", "contain");
```

The complete project can be found here:

https://github.com/joe-santy/redditSlideshow

Comment: Looks like the css functions are applying to your image container. Try making your image have a width of 100% and height of auto?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that did it.